Where do we go if we gain knowledge of the absolute truth?
One of the fundamental questions that humans since the dawn of time have asked themselves is why are we here?, or how are we here?, how did all this happen to be?
Philosophers try to answer these questions. Scientists try to determine the natural laws and how the physical world is as it is, Religions have their own ideas as to answers to these questions.
With the premise that there is knowledge of the absolute truth.
What are we gonna do if we gain that knowledge. Where do we go from there?

The classic answer to the meaning of everything, "42", is kinda meant to highlight this problem. Cause the answer is... nowhere, you're here, and you'll still be here. Everything is the same if you know (unless we live in some wacky reality like where one of the religions is true, I guess)

Only God. No "absolutes" at all for humans.

(Presuming God, or course.)

@MauroALLEGRANZA Ah my favorite maxim: there are no maxims

You are right here where you've always been. Consider looking in to Nonduality.

@ScottRowe non dualism or monism as I've just interpreted from a brief study  is in a basis of holism. A school of approach beginning in the East and opposes Western reductionism. My point is are these schools of thought and their approach in the analysis of the world a means of gaining the same absolute truth?. Different path same conclusion?

I think of Nonduality (not the Philosophical kind) as "seeing it". Everything else is: covering it with obscuring concepts.

@ScottRowe You must have an active mind. My mind is dull and uncomplicated and is not obscured by contradictory ocluding thoughts. What the hell do I know!!!

You may be interested in Arthur C. Clarke's classic The Nine Billion Names of God.

Your question is founded on the assumption that the human condition is such that it must always be striving. Perhaps that assumption is flawed. Perhaps once we know the ultimate truth, we won't feel the need to strive anymore, and will have to develop the need to enjoy remaining where we are?

"What are we gonna do if we gain that knowledge. Where do we go from there?". It will likely be determined to a large extent by what that knowledge is.

@Community Although this question does not have a known answer to be a fact and each person would speculate there own answer I believe its a good question and should be reopened. It has had over a thousand views and I know this is not a popularity contest but I think its a good question and stimulates the mind philosophically?

You ask:

Where do we go if we gain knowledge of the absolute truth?

Well, you are starting your philosophical career in the right place, among philosophers, so Philosophy StackExchange is a good start. If you really take it seriously, you have two options: a university or a library. The advantage of a university is that there are professional philosophers and intellectuals who can get you started, and the advantage of a library is there are no tests and admission is free!
The question you ask is an epistemological question because it is concerned with 'truth' and 'knowledge'. Epistemologists, one prominent example being Robert Audi, spend their adult lives asking and answering these sorts of questions. They build up their personal library of thinking to address questions such as yours. You get to meet these people at universities, and again that's a plus for the ivory tower.
I'm not sure that 'absolute truth' is a defensible idea. People often use the phrase, and it might be read as the truth of an absolutist. From WP:

In philosophy, universality or absolutism is the idea that universal facts exist and can be progressively discovered, as opposed to relativism, which asserts that all facts are relative to one's perspective. Absolutism and relativism have been explored at length in contemporary analytic philosophy.

If this is what you mean by absolute truth, then there are two popular contemporary sources: fundamentalist religion which tends to promote their religious doctrine as absolute truths as divinely revealed by God or gods depending on their flavor, and scientism, which in a strong form is fundamentalist about the application of the scientific method. (There are weaker forms of scientism which are comfortable with relativity of various forms, for instance anti-realist thinkers who label themselves instrumentalists).
Of course, there are also certain people who are philosophically inflexible who tend to consider themselves the sole font of absolute truth, and you'll certainly run across them (even in this forum)! So, before you find this magical place that deals in "absolute truths", figure out exactly what you mean by 'absolute truth', and reflect on whether truths are absolute at all, or whether you're willing to make room for a little relativism in your thinking.
Good luck!

Thanks for the answer I'm too long in the tooth to go to university . So I guess your gonna have to put up with my pestering and questioning on this site as my local library although it has a variety of books, it does not have a comprehensive catalogue of books on philosophy. I have a further question. If truth is relative to the observer. One person's truth is another person's lie how do we ever learn anything without a doubt in the other person's truth, How can we establish a consensus on knowledge if there is no absolute in the first place? Why the hell are we talking?

Big question in small space. My short version of belief: similar truth is rooted in similar experience, and similar experience is grounded in similar biology. We both have similar biology so we have similar truth. When enough people have similar truth, we have "objectivity" better understood as intersubjectivity. The why is understood in terms of our biology too: the Darwinian need for survival of the species. We are wired to use truth to conduct eusocial behavior...

Free to pester, but you're better off using chat.stackexchange.com and pinging me with the @ symbol, @8Mad0Manc8.

@8Mad0Manc8 Re "One person's truth is another person's lie how do we ever learn anything ..." etc: Read Karl Popper. Your library should have one of his popular books, and if not, suggest they buy one (libraries are surprisingly responsive! It's their job to cater to the readers!). There is also a ton online, of course. I also really like William James' pragmatism, a sort of Turing test for statements: "Reality" is elusive, but if a statement is helpful we can consider it true.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica or, we could just stop at 'helpful' and not worry about 'true'. Would save no end of trouble, especially in Morality.

@ScottRowe Truth and morality are imho quite orthogonal categories. (In particular, truth is assigned to factual statements which, as such, do not lend themselves to moral assessment; and moral judgement is applied to acts or thoughts quite independent of their reality.) James did emphatically not claim that helpful acts or thoughts are moral.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica In the uk laws and acts you should follow are made by elected represented figures in the outcome a collective vote..and determine acceptable acts and the unacceptable.. So they are a public consus of a cillective reality and not a solipsistic reality.

@8Mad0Manc8 I did no mean to reject the notion of a collective reality -- a concept that appears very useful, and hence can be regarded as true!

There's an old Buddhist parable that applies here:

Before enlightenment; chop wood, carry water.
After enlightenment; chop wood, carry water.

Grasping absolute truth (the Western analog of enlightenment) changes your attitude and your capabilities. It doesn't change your intrinsic nature, but merely reveals it. You'll still have to eat, earn a living, clean your house, pay your taxes… C'est la vie!
Nothing in the world changes from higher understanding. What changes is the relationship we hold to the world-as-it-is.

Same sh!t different day? :-)

@8Mad0Manc8:more like 'same shit, different attitude.'

I always liked that zen koan..

@8Mad0Manc8 "No yesterday, no tomorrow, no today."

@ScottRowe That comment, how I interpret it is like determinism or fate. Every moment in time contains every moment of time and our experience of time is just as an observer of those "events". They are something,, or what adds up to nothing, in the end?

Unfortunately you do not tell us what you consider the characteristics of “the absolute truth”. Hence I answer your question under the assumption

to consider an absolute truth to be a proposition with an ultimate
justification (German: “letztbegründet”).

Examples of such such propositions are mathemathical propositions which have been proven within a mathematical theory.

But I assume that mathematical propositions are not the theme of
your question. Then the situation is rather bad for ultimate
justification. History shows: In philosophy and in science no general propositions with an ultimate
justification have been found. As a consequence, the
search for ultimate justification seems to be a dead end.
A way out is Popper’s proposal to consider general statements not as
candidates for ultimate justification but as hypotheses which can be
confirmed or refuted, but not proven.


+1 Certainly "absolute truth" isn't clear. "letztbegründet" Was für einer Fachbegriff! I wish English had retained it's love of the compounding. We'd be so much smarter for it.

Even in math there is no absolute truth. Before the invention of i, which is √(-1), it was true that √(-1) is impossible.

@WeatherVane "There is no real number x with x^2=-1". This proposition was true previousy and is true also today. Buter later it was detected, that one can enlarge the domain of real numbers by introducing complex numbers. The result is still a field with addition, multiplication and the inverse operations. - Progress in mathematics often provides answers to old questions, it does not invalidate previous proofs.

That is my point: imaginary numbers are true when used as a stepping stone in calculations, but are false in the real world. Like god (and perhaps catalysts) if their use enables reaching a result that is verifiable in the real world, it doesn't matter if the stepping stone isn't 'real'.

So death and taxes are not a universal truth?

Are imaginary numbers "false in the real world"? Only if using "real" in the sense of "real numbers", I suppose. Otherwise, "imaginary" has always been a poor term for something that has "real" applications: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285520/where-exactly-are-complex-numbers-used-in-the-real-world

@8Mad0Manc8 Clearly, death and taxes are not equally universal truths. They are handed out in smaller installments to the well-off.

You've completely missed my point. Before the 16th century, √(-1) was considered impossible. (It still is, but it became a useful concept for math).

@WeatherVane Possibly it could help to look up in a book about elementary number theory what natural, rational, irrational, transcendent, real and complex numbers are in mathematics. The names are misleading if one asks for the ontological status.

It would help with what? Help me understand that complex math was a thing before 16th century?

@WeatherVane To understand that all these numbers are mathematical objects with the same(!) ontologial status.

They are now, but they weren't then. Truth is not absolute (except that a mathematician might say that this always was true). Please don't patronise me.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica ain't that the truth!!

@WeatherVane - Math is kind of like Comedy: there are some basic truths, but to earn a living you have to constantly come up with surprising new material. Fortunately, it's a Material World, we're never gonna run out.

@ScottRowe aren't they called axioms? Let's imagine that a square root of -1 exists, and call it i and see what follows.

Sure, make up any axioms you want, but some people might not be amused by them :-) Didn't the Pythagoreans kill people for talking about the dodecahedron? (the Math Mafia)

Ha-ha, let's imagine that three diverse and incompatible people share an apartment and make a sitcom :)

Why Mathematicians live alone.

There are many absolute truths:
There are no round squares.
There are no square circles.
All bachelors are unmarried.
Knowledge of these absolute truths has not had a profound influence on my life.
In the sciences, uncertainty is the killer of absolute truths and since uncertainty is prevalent (the Uncertainty principle), science will not claim any absolute truths.

Now I'm wondering about unmarried circles and square batchelors... I heard of a woman whose last name was batchelor. She was divorced.

That's set theory? if there is a class of something and that class has properties that determine it to be different from another thing then everything that has those properties will be counted as a member of that set and not in another class. Like object orientated programming.  Logic and set theory overlap. There are no square circles etc because each of the objects of that statement belong in a different class and do not overlap?

@8Mad0Manc8 and we know how 'OOPS' turned out. The TLA says it all

If we attain absolute knowledge, then it will change our belief system, it will affect how we interact with each other. For many people absolute knowledge has already been achieved. For example- Religions offers absolute knowledge. Religion changes the mindset of individuals. Religion offers many rituals and practices for salvation.
Science also offers absolute knowledge. For example - speed of light is constant irrespective of who measures it. Science offers new technology. Even if understand everything ,there will be new technological innovations every year for many years to come.
Absolute knowledge is not the end of the road. There are many ways to apply that knowledge in our daily lives thus transforming us into a subjectively better person.

Knowledge makes beliefs unnecessary. However, "If I have all knowledge and understand all mysteries, and have all faith, so as to remove mountains, but have not love, I am nothing."

@ScottRowe I like that quote is it from your own mind or some other person's mind or a collective  religous text?

@8Mad0Manc8 1 COR 13

Where do we go if we gain knowledge of the absolute truth?
The answer is: You are a human. You cannot gain absolute truth. You would go insane, or your head would explode.
Something created this world. It's beautiful. Why do you need to know more. Just enjoy it.
Zen and insanity
"Phaedrus's philosophical investigations eventually caused him to become insane, and he was subjected to electroconvulsive therapy, which permanently changed his personality."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Community "so that others can confirm that your answer is correct"?!? That's the whole point, ya see, there's no bloomin' absolute truth (although there is absolut vodka and absolute zero and a few other things) so no one is ever going to know except within themselves and they'll probably keep quiet about it!

@ScottRowe I agree with you. Absolutely.

Enjoy it, and this world in my experience seldom go together, but don't listen to me. I'm just an old  cynic.
